# Auto-Reply to Messages Sent to Mailing List

Tags: email, sendmail, procmail

## Background and Current Situation

I inherited a CentOS 5.7 box running Mailman 2.1.9 housing a series of legacy mailing lists. I've been working on moving these lists to other services like Exchange mailing lists and have simply been aliasing the mailing list on the current mailman box to the new Exchange list which is a great short term fix for getting users to use the new lists.

I'd ultimately like to phase out this box and remove it from production but for a few months at least I'd like to auto-reply to (but not forward) messages sent to the old lists and let clients know that the list is going to be phased out and ideally inform them of the new list address.

## The Question

What would be the best way to take messages sent to `training@subdomain.domain.tld` where the current alias in `/etc/aliases` looks like `training: "|/usr/lib/mailman/mail/mailman post training"`and reply to the sender with a message? I've read in a number of places that procmail or the vacation package are the best bets but I can't seem to find any guidance on how to adapt these solutions to large numbers of aliases where there aren't actual users behind the alias.

One Caveat is that the lists aren't transitioning one for one (i.e. `training@subdomain.domain.tld` isn't becoming `training@domain.tld`) so I can't simply do a blanket redirect or simply update the MX records to point to a new set of mail servers.

## Environment Details

Below are some details about the current box and installed packages:

- CentOS 5.7
- Mailman 2.1.9
- Procmail 3.22
- Sendmail 8.13.8
- Postfix 2.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is hazy on the details, and I have a bad feeling you are making the whole thing more complex than it needs to be (do you really need to rename the mailing lists? What is it about Exchange that makes it not worse?) but to attempt to answer your concrete question, you should be able to add a second destination to the alias which runs the responder, then passes the message to Mailman, or forwards to the new list address, or whatever.  (Of course, if you just want to send the reply, you don't need the original destination any longer; but it is worth pointing out that this is a possibility.)

```
training: "|/usr/local/bin/autoreply training", "|/usr/lib/mailman/mail/mailman post training"
```

where `/usr/local/bin/autoreply` might look something like

```
#!/bin/sh
######## WARNING: not properly investigated
vacation -a "$1" -m /etc/vacation.msg -f /etc/vacation -e /etc/vacation
```

I have not investigated whether it is possible or sensible to run `vacation` with these options, and it also depends on which user you are running this action as (`sendmail`?).  You need to set things up so that the user who runs this script has write access to the resources the program is trying to use; maybe even create a separate user for this purpose.  As a starting point, if you can run `vacation -I` with the above options as root and then change the owner of the files it creates to the user you want to use for this, you should be all set.

Obviously, if you want to use Procmail instead of `vacation`, you can pretty much copy and paste the traditional recipe from [`man procmailex`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/procmailex) -- because it is made up from simple pieces, it might be easier to adapt to your circumstances if you can't get `vacation` to work reasonably in this setting.

... Or look into something like http://www.brandonchecketts.com/archives/vacation-autoreply-message-with-virtual-users-and-postfix as a one-stop replacement for the regular `vacation` program.  If your end goal is simply to shut down things ASAP, you might want to consider replacing Sendmail with Postfix just so you have a simpler and more secure system during the transition period, and then the virtual vacation responder instructions behind the link should be easy to just plug and play. (See also https://benjaminjchapman.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/creating-a-vacation-message-in-centos/ for a sort of middle ground.)

Comment: My apologies for being a little scarce on the reasoning. Much like in the last link you posted the server is being run by my local IT group at a university but we're transitioning everything to centrally managed mailing lists which includes a new naming scheme and a phaseout of many legacy lists. 

I'm working my way through the options you provided and many seem feasible, I'll find the _most_ feasible and post my results and mark this as a solution if something here helps or leads to a solution which I think it will.